# Remove embedded subtitle streams from media file without "streaming/remuxing"

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, subtitles, matroska

[This related post gives a solution:](https://superuser.com/a/609278/1006358)

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv input.mkv -S # remove all subtitle tracks
```

[This other related post gives a solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52543728/8871635)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -map_metadata 0:g -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a -movflags +faststart -threads 8 -sn removed.mp4
```

However, both of these solutions require "streaming" all the video/audio tracks to another file, and just skip adding the subtitle streams. Is it possible to simply remove the subtitle track(s) from a movie file without having to stream anything?

Streaming video/audio tracks require significant resources, time, and is basically a remux. I'd like to simply remove the embedded subtitles and touch nothing else... Usually it is a `.mkv` file, but it could be other formats (e.g. `.mp4` as well).

Comment: Not possible with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Is it possible some other way (such as @Moab's comment)?

I didn't specifically ask for a way to do this using ffmpeg. I have edited the title, and I will leave `ffmpeg` since it is quite relevant and is a popular tag.

Comment: what would be a better tag to add?

Answer (score 3):

The `-sn` option does exactly that.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Subtitle-options

> `-sn (input/output)`
> ...
> As an output option, disables subtitle recording i.e. automatic
> selection or mapping of any subtitle stream. For full manual control
> see the -map option.

Example:

`ffmpeg -i video.mkv -c copy -sn video.sn.mkv`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't think it answers the question though, due to it still requiring "streaming" of the video/audio tracks as described in my post. Additionally, in my post, I put a command that already includes the `-sn` option.

Comment: Now I understand what you want to achieve. I'm not sure if `ffmpeg` is able to overwrite the source file directly. Also if something goes wrong, the source file will get corrupted. It would be cool to have a tool that lets us open the file as if it were a folder, so that we would then be able to remove its content just like we do when using a file explorer/manager. But I'm not sure that such a tools exists.

Comment: Thanks, you described it a bit better than I did -- "opening the file like a folder and taking out a particular track". This explanation makes sense (with the consequence that you will have to essentially make a copy of the original file with modifications such as removing a track).